# Serialize/Deserialize Custom Dataclass Python with class definitions

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization, networkx

I have a few custom dataclasses I want to serialize and save within a networkx graph. But I also want to save the class definitions alongside the serialized JSON string so I can deserialize them back into those objects.

These can be nested custom objects, for example:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Fruit:
   name: str 
   color: str 
   picked_on: dt.datetime

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Apple(Fruit):
   orchard: str
```

Then the serialized data would look something like

```
dumped = json.dumps(json_graph.node_link_data(<graph with Apples/Fruits>)
```

I plan on saving the `dumped` data into a JSON file, but I also need to snapshot what the dataclasses look like at the moment so I can deserialize that JSON file with that version of the dataclass. This is because the dataclass could change over time and I want to retrieve the graph at any moment in time.

Is there a good way to do the deserialization like that? How would I save the dataclass definitions alongside the actual data?

So I'd like to also save a file somewhere with a JSON mapping something like

```
{"Fruit": {"name": str, "color": str, "picked_on": dt.datetime}, "Apple": {"parent": "Fruit", "orchard": str}}
```